# Saving Bytes Vapor Swift

Tags: swift, postgresql, byte, vapor

I need some help about saving bytes in Vapor : 
I have this Image class :

```
class Image: Model {
var id: Node?
var datas: Bytes
var name: String
var exists: Bool = false

init(name: String, datas: Bytes) {
    self.name = name
    self.datas = datas
}

// NodeInitializable
required init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
    self.id = try node.extract("id")
    self.datas = try node.extract("datas")
    self.name = try node.extract("name")
}

// NodeRepresentable
func makeNode(context: Context) throws -> Node {
    return try Node(node: ["id": id,
                           "name": name,
                           "datas": datas.string()
                           ])
}

// Preparation
static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {


    try database.create("images") { categories in
        categories.id()
        categories.string("name")
        categories.data("datas")
    }


}

static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
    try database.delete("images")
}
```

}

I'm sending with Postman a POST request with this body :

`{
    "name": "politique.jpg",
    "datas": [122, 122]
}`

Then It creates a new line in my Database with datas.

But when i try a GET on this image, i have this error when extracting object :

> Could not initialize Image, skipping: unableToConvert(node:
>   Optional(Node.Node.bytes([101, 110, 111, 61])), expected: "UInt8")

What i'm doing wrong here ? Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extract` method does not support initializing arrays in Vapor 1. You'll need to manually pull out the data using something like:

```
self.datas = node["datas"]?.bytes ?? []
```

#### Why?

The issue is that it's pretty difficult for us to tell when something like `[1,2,3]` is an array of individual JSON numbers, and when it's meant to represent a collection of data. For example:

```
scores: [1, 10, 44, 5]
```

Would likely want to be an array of JSON where something like:

```
image: [1, 10, 44, 5]
```

represents raw data.

In general, because individual objects are more common, we prioritize that and users must opt-in to access bytes and things through the conveniences we have like the code above.

Comment: This looked so promising. However, when I try the line: `self.datas = node["datas"]?.bytes ?? []` I get the error `Enum element 'bytes' cannot be referenced as an instance member`. Any thoughts? Cheers